# golang git - Is there a way to pull latest from remote branch if the repo is already cloned rather than cloning it again

Tags: go, go-git

I have a repo which needs to be cloned daily for some data. Is there a way in golang using go-git library to clone the repo only once and update the repo using git pull?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there's [`Worktree.Pull()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git/v5#Worktree.Pull) method exactly for that.

```golang
    // Open already cloned repo in path
    r, err := git.PlainOpen(path)
    
    // Get the working directory
    w, err := r.Worktree()
    
    // Pull from origin
    err = w.Pull(&git.PullOptions{RemoteName: "origin"})
```

(skipped error checking for better readability)

Comment: pull throws git.ErrNonFastForwardUpdate for me, had to ignore the error